# Is there a difference in terminology between velocity vs velocity of the center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, velocity, rotational-kinematics

I was wondering if there was a difference between velocity of the center of mass of an object vs finding the velocity of an object in general. The case I was looking at was in a ball rolling without slipping. I know that in the case of a ball rolling without slipping, the velocity of the center of mass would simply = rw, but if a question asks for the velocity, would I also have to factor in the tangential velocity alongside the velocity of the center of mass? I think I might have a misunderstanding somehow? Or would the tangential velocity vectors simply all cancel out which makes it a non-factor?

Comment: By definition all the tangential vectors cancel out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the velocity of a rigid body is the velocity of its center of mass.The various points on the rigid body can have different velocities as in the case of a rolling ball without slipping. The center of mass moves with a velocity which is equal to the mass-weighted average of local velocities .